# Error installing Gforth on OS X Mavericks (10.9) with Homebrew

Tags: c++, macos, build, forth, gforth

I'm trying to install [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth) on my [MacBook Air](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air) (running OS X Mavericks (10.9)), but a `brew install gforth` produces the following error:

```
Error: gforth dependency libffi was built with the following
C++ standard library: libstdc++ (from clang)

This is incompatible with the standard library being used
to build gforth: libc++ (from clang)

Please reinstall libffi using a compatible compiler.
```

I know *what* the issue is (libffi was built with an older version of the C++ standard library), but I'm not sure how to fix this issue with [Homebrew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29). Can I uninstall libffi and reinstall it with libc++ via Homebrew, or do I need to resort to more drastic measures?

Comment: The issue does not occur to me on a fresh Homebrew installation, possibly it's been fixed